# Effecient way to serialize jagged arrays using BinaryWriter

Tags: serialization, jagged-arrays, binarywriter

stackoverflowers.

I am basically wondering if anyone has got a tip on how I should go on about this. I am already serializing regular primitive types using the BinaryWriter (by length prefixing byte arrays).
Normally I would just add another entity to the primitivetypes dictionary that I have, but I want to be able to serialize an indefinite jagged array; where it doesn't matter if it's a `System.Byte[][]` or `System.Byte[][][][][][]`

I would need a way to prefix all the arrays' lengths and also a way to tell the deserializer how many arrays of arrays there are.

I am just thinking of a good way to do this, but I have been trying all day.

Just a snippet of what I have come up with (it's not complete at all, but maybe you get my conceptional approach);

```
     Private Sub WriteArray(Writer As BinaryWriter, Type As Byte, Array As Array)
    Writer.Write(Array.GetLength(0)) 'Writing length so we know how many arrays there are.
    Dim Current As Type = Array.GetType() 'Getting the type of the (jagged-)array
    If Current.HasElementType AndAlso Current.GetElementType.IsArray Then 'Checking whether it's a jagged-array.
        Writer.Write(True) 'Writing true; which represents that it's a jagged-array.
        For Each A As Array In Array
            WriteArray(Writer, Type, A) 'Looping through the same method until...
        Next
    Else '... It's not jagged. -- This way is problematic; most of the times there are multiple jagged-arrays.
        Writer.Write(False) 'Not jagged.
        Select Case Type
            Case 0 '0 = byte, I use other bytes for strings/integers/etc.
                For Each Obj As Byte In Array
                    Writer.Write(Obj) 'Because it's not jagged we can finally write the bytes
                Next
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope to see you take part in the discussion, and that we might come up with a solution.

Comment: Is there any point in writing this code yourself when you can simply use BinaryFormatter and be done in 2 minutes?

Comment: Indeed, because I am working with client -> server programs; where the BinaryFormatter is complicated, especially if I want to use this for other programming languages.

Comment: Well, don't design a Mercedes when all you need is a bicycle.  If you want a general purpose serializer then look at Json or Protobuf.

Comment: @HansPassant I prefer staying with my generic BinaryRead/Writer serializer; it's widely implemented in my projects, thus I just want to keep using it. In fact, I prefer having everything generic; without using any DLLs or such.